# Windows Phone 8.1 app description multi-language

Tags: c#, upload, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, publish

Alright, so I've been trying to upload my application but I can't seem te get the option to put descriptions in multiple languages.
The only language popping up is my default language (en-US).

I've already try'd to add a 'Strings' folder and add multiple language folders + resource files into it.
But it doesn't actually give me the chance to add multiple descriptions (languages) after the package has been uploaded.

Anyone knows how to?

Thanks.

EDIT: My resources files were empty, after filling in one single string the store noticed the different languages.

Comment: Firstly you will need to upload the package you created. Remember the different languages resources that you added should be present inside the specific folder path in your project that Microsoft specifies with correct names such as `en, en-au, en-ca, en-gb, en-ie, en-in, en-nz, en-sg, en-us, en-za, en-bz, en-hk, en-id...`. Cause store then identifies based on these resources which language desc it should ask publisher to enter

Comment: Jerin, thanks for your help. I guess I can't use empty resource files. I had made the resource files but didn't use them because I use in-app translations using a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. double Click on Package.appxmanifest
2. Open With...XML(Text) Editor
3. Find this:

`<Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>`

4. Change with this:

   ```
    <Resources>
       <Resource Language="en-US" />
       <Resource Language="it-IT"/>
     </Resources>
   ```

Comment: I'll give this a try as soon as I have to upload a new project or update. As soon as it worked I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks.